# Evaluate $\int \frac{\sqrt{1+x^4}}{1-x^4}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How to evaluate

> $$\int \frac{\sqrt{1+x^4}}{1-x^4}dx.$$

If we substitute $x=\sqrt{\tan{\theta}}$, it becomes
$$\int \frac{1}{2\cos{\theta}\cos{2\theta}\sqrt{\tan{\theta}}}d\theta.$$

What can I do next ?

**Edit**

Are these steps correct ?

$$=\int \frac{1}{2\cos{\theta}\cos{2\theta}\sqrt{\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}}}d\theta$$

$$=\int \frac{1}{2\cos{2\theta}\sqrt{\cos^2 \theta\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}}}d\theta$$

$$=\int \frac{1}{2\cos{2\theta}\sqrt{\cos^2 \theta\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}}}d\theta$$

$$=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\cos{2\theta}\sqrt{\sin{2 \theta}}}d\theta$$

Now If we substitute $t=\sin{2\theta}$, it becomes

$$=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}(1-t^2)\sqrt{t}}dt$$

$$=\int \frac{\frac{1}{t^2}}{\sqrt{2}\frac{(1-t^2)}{t}\sqrt{\frac{t}{t^2}}}dt$$

$$=\int \frac{\frac{1}{t^2}}{\sqrt{2}(\frac{1}{t} -t)\sqrt{\frac{1}{t}}}dt$$

Now If we substitute $u^2=\frac{1}{t}$, it becomes

$$=\int \frac{-2u}{\sqrt{2}(u^2 -\frac{1}{u^2})u}du$$

$$=\int \frac{-u^2}{\sqrt{2}(u^4 -1^2)}du$$

$$=\int \frac{-u^2}{\sqrt{2}(u^2 +1)(u^2-1)}du$$

$$=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\int \frac{u^2+1+u^2-1}{(u^2 +1)(u^2-1)}du$$

This can be solved easily now and we will get an elementary solution.

But Wolfram alpha gives a solution in non elementary functions.

Therefore I am confused. I guess the above solution is correct only for some restricted values of x.

Comment: I don't think it is possible for a human to calculate it correctly as the Wolfram alpha gives this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5Bsqrt%5C%2840%291%2BPower%5Bx%2C4%5D%5C%2841%29%2C1-Power%5Bx%2C4%5D%5D%5C%2841%29%2Cx%5D

Comment: Try to factor $1\pm x^4$ or substitute $x=\sqrt[4]y$ and factor the result. In the end, you will use [Appel $F_1$’s definite integral representation](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/AppellF1/07/01/01/) after using $\int_0^z$ instead of $\int$

Comment: I got one solution from [this](https://d3cvwyf9ksu0h5.cloudfront.net/answer-1629821737_65019.mp4).Is this answer only correct for some restricted values of x ? If yes then for which value ? Because Wolfram alpha gives answer in non elementary function but this gives answer in elementary functions.

Comment: Both answers are probably correct. Not that I verified it, but just because WolframAlpha isn't able to give an elementary solution doesn't always mean there isn't one, as that video shows. There are probably some restricted values on what $x$ is and you can mention what they are, but the whole point of indefinite integration is to just find that general antiderivative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alternatively, substitute $t=\frac{\sqrt2 x}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}$. Then
$$\frac{\sqrt{1+x^4}}{1-x^4}=\frac{xt}{\sqrt2(t^2-x^2)}, \>\>\>\>\>dx =\frac{x}{t(1-t^2x^2)}dt$$
and
\begin{align}
&\int \frac{\sqrt{1+x^4}}{1-x^4}dx\\
=&\ \frac1{\sqrt2}\int \frac{x^2}{(t^2-x^2)(1-t^2 x^2)}dt
= \frac1{\sqrt2}\int \frac1{t^2(\frac1{x^2}+x^2)-1-t^4}dt\\
=& \frac1{\sqrt2}\int \frac1{1-t^4}dt= \frac1{2\sqrt2}\int \frac1{1-t^2}+ \frac1{1+t^2}\ dt\\
=& \ \frac1{2\sqrt2}\left(\tanh^{-1}t +\tan^{-1}t\right)+C
\end{align}

Comment: How did you think about that substitution ?

Answer (score 2):

Maple also gives a non-elementary answer to the original integral in terms of elliptic integral functions.  However, for the integral over $\theta$ it does give an elementary answer, which translated back to the original integral becomes

$$ \frac{\sqrt{2}\, \mathrm{arctanh}\! \left(\sqrt{\sin\left(2 \arctan \! \left(x^{2}\right)\right)}\right)}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{2}\, \arctan \! \left(\sqrt{\sin\left(2 \arctan \! \left(x^{2}\right)\right)}\right)}{4}$$

which is correct for $x > 0$ (for $x < 0$ you want to multiply that by $-1$).

I believe both Maple and Wolfram Alpha use some form of the Risch algorithm to decide whether an integral is elementary, however in the algebraic case, which the original integral is, the implementation seems not to be complete.

Comment: It's perhaps worth mentioning that expanding the radicand using the double-angle identity gives a rational expression: $\sin (2 \arctan (x^2)) = \frac{2 x}{1 + x^4}$.